# regex expression to convert currency format

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex expression for converting user input into currency format,
but I don't know how it works. I am learner in Regex Help me.

```
    return "$" + num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
```

I also need negative numbers to be in currency format how can i achieve this?

```
    example
        -254182=> -254,182.00
```

Comment: Plesse provide an example for what the user gives in and what should be given back.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it apart:

```
"$"                                       # literal $ sign
num.toFixed(2)                            # round up to 2 decimal points
replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") # places comma after every 3 digits
```

Placement of comma after every 3 digits is done using a lookahead regex that asserts that there are 1 more sets of **3 digits** ahead finally followed by a non-digit.

Example:

```
var num = 1234567.8685;
var fmt = "$" + num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
//=> $1,234,567.87
```

Comment: I also want to allow negative numbers to be in currency format how can i achieve this?

Comment: That was not part of your question. You should edit the question with examples.

Comment: `num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")` already converts `-254182` to `-254,182.00`, isn't it what you want?